# iOS 14 widget on SwiftUI with project on storyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, storyboard

Can I add a target with iOS 14 widget extention (swift ui) to a project that is built on storyboard?

Comment: yes, widget is in SwiftUI.just add and try ;)

Comment: Yes, you can use this

Comment: yes :) but i have storyboard main interface, and i dont know, may i add WidgetExtention to this

Comment: The code for your widget will be in your Widget extension. It won't / can't use anything that is on your storyboard. Though depending on your app, you may be able to share code.